# how to stop while do in shell once a string is not found?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do

    if tail -1 /tmp/test | grep 'line3'
    then
        echo found
        sleep 5
    else
        echo not found
    fi
done
```

It looks for `line3` every 5 seconds. How do I make the script stop once `line3` is not found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear why you are including `while [ true ]` around your `tail | grep` and `if, then, else` as the `while` loop can use your clause as the test itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

while tail -1 /tmp/test | grep 'line3'
do
    echo found
    sleep 5
done

echo "not found"
```

There is nothing wrong with wrapping `if, then, else` in `while [ true ]`, it is just less than optimal.

Comment: Thank you, this one is simpler, I'll use it :)

Answer (score 6):

Use logical breaking. No need to break.

```
#!/bin/bash

match=1

while [ ${match} -eq 1 ]
do

    if tail -1 /tmp/test | grep 'line3'
    then
        echo found
        sleep 5
    else
        match=0
        echo not found
    fi
done
```

Comment: You could also have !${match} and set match to 1 in the loop

Comment: yup :). Did it just for simplicity so that user can understand it easily.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED**

```
    #!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do

    if tail -1 /tmp/test | grep 'line3'
    then
        echo found
        sleep 5
    else
        echo not found
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `while [ true ]` is still superfluous.  `[ true ]` does not do what you think it does -- `while true` would be more idiomatic.