# Count how many occurrences in a day with bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script to automatically connect my modem when my internet is disconnected and write a log when that happens, my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S`
echo -n $DATE >> /www/restart.log
echo ' Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN' >> /www/restart.log
sleep 20
while [ true ]
do
    if tail -1 /www/vpn.log | grep 'Initialization Sequence Completed'
    then
        sleep 5
    else
        profile start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S`
        echo -n $DATE >> /www/restart.log
        echo ' Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart' >> /www/restart.log
        echo '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'      >> /www/restart.log
        rm /www/vpn.log
        break
    fi
done
```

The script is terminated after it reconnects the internet (I have a reason for this, please don't ask me why) and is run again when the internet is up. The log looks like this:

```
05-01-2015_09:49:49 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
05-01-2015_10:32:45 Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-01-2015_10:33:20 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
05-01-2015_11:27:59 Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-01-2015_11:28:46 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
```

I want to count how many reconnects happen in a day, I want the log file to be something like this:

```
05-01-2015_09:49:49 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
05-01-2015_10:32:45 Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart
05-01-2015_10:32:59 Your internet has been reconnected for 6 times today
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-01-2015_10:33:20 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
05-01-2015_11:27:59 Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart
05-01-2015_10:32:59 Your internet has been reconnected for 7 times today
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-01-2015_10:33:20 Internet terkoneksi ke server OpenVPN
05-01-2015_11:27:59 Openvpn Disconnected. Koneksi internet direstart
05-01-2015_10:32:59 Your internet has been reconnected for 8 times today
```

Is that possible ? Please note that my script is terminated after it reconnects the modem and is called again when the internet is up, I don't want my script to run 24 hours a day.

Comment: Use `grep` and `wc` on the existing log file before adding anything to it. Learn about those tools to figure out how to filter based on the date.

Comment: `while [ true ]` happens to work for coincidental reasons, but it doesn't do what you think it does.  You probably mean `while true` ... oh, it's [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739195/how-to-stop-while-do-in-shell-once-a-string-is-not-found/27739230#comment43889924_27739230) again.

Comment: Well sorry for being a noob on this, just don't answer if you feel bothered with my posts

Comment: ^^ When someone is trying to correct you, it's usually for helping you learn. Don't get offended by that. & by the way `while [ true ]` & `while [ false ]` both will give same results here. `while true` & `while false` results will differ.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not offended. Sorry for my language.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to keep the log file clean, and create a separate log analyzer script to count the number of connections per day.

```
cut -s -d_ -f1 reconnect.log | uniq -c
```